# Separate Tuples Values and Assign in Pinescript TradingView

Tags: arrays, loops, tuples, pine-script, tradingview-api

I was trying to display intrabar close values inside the current chart's bar(15 min). So there are three values. But the values comes as tuple.
I cannot separate the tuples to three values. I have tried the below code as well as using for loop(which I am not familiar with),

```
[fir, sec, thi] = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "5", close)
var table top_boxes = table.new(position.bottom_center, 6, 2)
table.cell(top_boxes, 0, 0, text=str.tostring(a), bgcolor=color.new(color.blue, 0), text_color=color.white, width=4, height=8)
table.cell(top_boxes, 1, 0, text=str.tostring(b), bgcolor=color.new(color.red, 0), text_color=color.white, width=4, height=8)
table.cell(top_boxes, 1, 0, text=str.tostring(c), bgcolor=color.new(color.yellow, 0), text_color=color.white, width=4, height=8)
```

Can someone help me to separate the values in the array and display them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only request `close` price, `request.security_lower_tf()` function returns an array with 3 elements.

You can get the value of each element using `array.get()`:

```
close_5 = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "5", close)
var table top_boxes = table.new(position.bottom_center, 6, 2)
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(top_boxes, 0, 0, text=str.tostring(array.get(close_5, 0)), bgcolor=color.new(color.blue, 0), text_color=color.white, width=4, height=8)
    table.cell(top_boxes, 1, 0, text=str.tostring(array.get(close_5, 1)), bgcolor=color.new(color.red, 0), text_color=color.white, width=4, height=8)
    table.cell(top_boxes, 2, 0, text=str.tostring(array.get(close_5, 2)), bgcolor=color.new(color.yellow, 0), text_color=color.white, width=4, height=8)
```

In some cases, there will be missing some 5 min bars in order to return 3 elements into that array. You can write a "safer" code using a `for` loop:

```
//@version=5
indicator("request 5 min timeframe", overlay = true)
close_5 = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "5", close)
var table top_boxes = table.new(position.bottom_center, 6, 2)

if barstate.islast
    color[] cell_bg_color = array.from(color.blue, color.red, color.yellow)
    for [index, price] in close_5
        table.cell(top_boxes, index, 0, text=str.tostring(price), bgcolor=array.get(cell_bg_color, index), text_color=color.white)
```

Comment: Study Error : In 'array.get()' function. Index 1 is out of bounds, array size is 1.

Comment: You are on a 15 min timeframe?

Comment: Yes, And we need to access the values of Intrabars. (Mentioned in the question also)

Comment: What’s the ticker you’re using?

Comment: Not any specific ticker. "Use syminfo.tickerid to request data from the chart's symbol." from their documentation. The values are deriving when we use if bar_index == last_bar_index - 1
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(arrClose)).
But cannot separate them.

Comment: The function returns an array of "5 min bar close price". If there are no 3 "5 min bars" that are constructing the "15 min bar", than you will have less elements in the array. For example, let's say that we request 30 min bar in this function, and we use 1 hour timeframe on any NASDAQ ticker. Since NASDAQ is closed on 16:00, the last bar is only 30 min, so we will get only 1 element in the array. I'll edit my answer in order to solve this issue also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249774/discussion-between-paulcab-and-mr-statler).